# Access files outside of DocumentRoot

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

http://site1.bla.example.com, http://site2.bla.example.com, and http://site2.bla.example.com all point to `/var/www/html` which is my DocumentRoot.

Given the following directory structure, I would like http://site1.bla.example.com/files/somefile1.png to return `somefile1.png`, http://site2.bla.example.com/files/somefile2.png to return `somefile2.png`, etc.

```
/var/www/html/index.php
/var/www/files/site1/somefile1.png
/var/www/files/site2/somefile2.png
/var/www/files/site3/somefile3.png
```

How is this accomplished?  Below is my unsuccessful attempt.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.bla.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    #This seems to work, but I wish to use regex
    # Alias /files/site1 /var/www/files/site1 

    #This doesn't work
    AliasMatch ^/files/(.+)$ /var/www/files/$1

    <Directory "/var/www/html">

        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteBase /

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.bla\.example\.com [NC] 
        RewriteRule ^public/([^//]+)$ public/%1/$1 [NC,L]

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: My rewrite regex was wrong, but fixed.  `Alias` seems to work, however, `AliasMatch` does not.  Any recommendations?

Comment: Saw an answer, clicked it, but it was gone!  Any ideas, please post.  Thank you